# saveFileDialog stop working + download a file from internet

Tags: c#, file, download, savefiledialog

I want to creat a function for update. When a new version appears, a inputbox will appears with a button for download. When I push that button, saveFileDialog will appear to save the file (new version) where I want.

I have this function:

```
public void descarcare()
    {

        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.CreatePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "myText";
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter ="Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                byte[] receivedData = webClient.DownloadData("http://startut.ro/smartAppointment.rar");
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create);
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

                bw.Write(receivedData);

                bw.Close();
                fs.Close();
                ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string message = e.Message;
                MessageBox.Show("Nu ai o conexiune de internet stabilită. Încearcă să te conectezi la internet, și după aceea să descarci noua versiune !", "EROARE CONEXIUNE INTERNET");
            }

        }
    }
```

Firstly I try with a test button to see if the function work, and after that I will implement in the inputbox.

```
 private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             descarcare();
        }
```

When i push the button, the saveFileDiaglog will appear and after that crash. The crash appear for any saveFileDialog. If i have only an saveFileDialog without any code, will crash, the probleme is the saveFileDialog.

Comment: First.) remove first line "saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();" It is useless !! Second.) how do you create "saveFileDialog1" ?

Comment: Now works. The probleme is this, when I run the program with Visual C# (Run Debugging) and the saveFileDialog appers, will crash, but if I try run the app with the executable, will work ! Thanks for all the answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove first line "saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();" It is useless !!

remove

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
```

from your function descarcare();

You should create it like this.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
....
    internal SaveFileDialog SaveFileDialog1;
....

    public Form1() : base()
    {   
                ....
                this.SaveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
                ....
```

for better code, you should set SaveFileDialog1 something like this.

```
....
SaveFileDialog1.CreatePrompt = true;
SaveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = true;
SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "myText";
SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = 
            "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = 
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
DialogResult result = SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                try
....
```

In the catch block you also should put the "message" to the output.

Comment: I add, but sitll crash ! I edit my initial message with your version.

Comment: Have you deleted the first "saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();"

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem

```
**DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();**
```

you need to change the code where you are doing 
    DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
to

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();  
// you need to Create an Instance of SaveFileDialog

var result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
  //do your logic here.. 
}
```

Comment: I want to make that the people can choose the filepath!

Comment: TransmitFile(FilePath + FileName should prompt the save Dialog have you tried it..?

Comment: I try your code, but I have an error that i don't know how to resolve !

Comment: do not use the exact variables replace them with the ones in your use case.. also what error are you getting..???

Comment: The type or namespace name "HttpContext" do not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'.

Comment: use the new example I also have shown how to dispose of the FileStream Oblect.

Comment: I don't know, but this error appear when the saveFileDialog1 appears on the screen: 'vshost32.exe stopped working'

Comment: For starters please show the full Method / Event.. actually can't tell where this code is being fired or expected to be triggered.. when you step thru the code.. where exactly is the error happening..

Comment: Ok, I have a function `private void descarca()` that includes your code. I call this function when i click on a text button: `private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` with this code: `descarca();`. When i click on the button, the saveFileDialog appears and after that, crash !

Comment: Please edit your original code and show all the methods that are relevant to the question..this is becoming a run around..thanks

Comment: Done, I edit. The app work perfectly, only when i push that button, will crash with that error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15866/discussion-between-andr3yy-and-dj-kraze)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code like this:

```
   saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

   if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {

       try
       {
           WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
           byte[] receivedData = webClient.DownloadData("http://startut.ro/smartAppointment.rar");
           FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create);
           BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

           bw.Write(receivedData);

           bw.Close();
           fs.Close();

       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           string message = e.Message;
           MessageBox.Show("Nu ai o conexiune de internet stabilită. Încearcă să te conectezi la internet, și după aceea să descarci noua versiune !", "EROARE CONEXIUNE INTERNET");
       }

   }
```

Comment: Then it means your app is failing somewhere else.

Comment: Is failing when the saveFileDialog is appear.

Answer (score 0):

With silverlight, due to security restrictions, they will not give you the location of the file you are saving.  You may, however, get a Stream object to the file the user selected by using the [OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog.openfile%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) function.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.michielpost.nl/PostDetail_25.aspx) for how to use the WebClient still with the Stream object.

Comment: Where does it say that he is using SilverLight AnDr3yy please clarify what type of web application you are implementing here..

Comment: I want to make a function that download a rar from internet ! Is a update function. And I want to make that people can choose the path where to save the file !

Comment: your title says save.. can you change it to say download a file and save to selected location something to effect

Comment: Firstly I try with saveFileDialog, I think that this is the way, but is not.

Comment: It was originally tagged Silverlight.  Not sure where it went.

Answer (score 0):

suggested to restructure the code as:-

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();    
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler (FileDownloaded);//Implement this method to notify the download.

   if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {

       try
       {               
           webClient.DownloadFileAsync("http://startut.ro/smartAppointment.rar", saveFileDialog1.FileName);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           string message = e.Message;
           MessageBox.Show("Nu ai o conecsiune de internet stabilită. Încearcă să te conectezi la internet, și după aceea să descarci noua versiune !", "EROARE CONECSIUNE INTERNET");
       }

   }
```

Further saveFileDialog1.FileName gives the fullpath where the file has to be saved so it should not be an issue.

However I will suggest using  `webClient.DownloadFileAsync` instead of `webClient.DownloadFile` because later is a blocking call.